# mysqli and prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot see to find the problem in this php code:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Champions(Spell 1) VALUES(?)")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $SP1);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
        else {
            printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        }
}
```

Just throws the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1) VALUES (?)' at line 1

Comment: What is `Spell 1` supposed to do in the query? That's a literal and a number, not a string or column name.

Comment: Try this
$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Champions('Spell 1') VALUES(?)")

Comment: If that's your field name, delimit it with backticks...  Poor choice for a field name though...

Comment: Ya I really should just use an underscore then I guess, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CAUSE YOU HAVE SPACE IN FIELD NAME

```
Spell 1
```

try with proper fieldname

```
INSERT INTO Champions(Spell 1) VALUES(?)
                           ^
```

or use quoting(not tried)

```
INSERT INTO Champions(`Spell 1`) VALUES(?)
```